# Orientation of local star map

Tags: milky-way, ecliptic, star-maps

This image depicts our solar neighborhood [image]
Source

The plane defined by the concentric circles, does it have a relationship to any galactic reference points or the ecliptic?

Answer (score 4):

By inspection of a star charting app, I'd say the circles lie in the celestial equator, ie declination equal 0 degrees.  Stars above the circles are to the north and vice versa.